# Выдача рандомного изображения с помощью js

Tags: javascript, html

В папке "@3" лежат 2 (в перспективе больше 150) изображения формата JPEG, их имена состоят из чисел, т. е. первое изображение - 1.jpg, второе - 2.jpg и т. д..
Нужна страница, которая выдаст одно случайное из 2 (в перспективе из более 150) изображений.
Мой код почему-то не работает.
Код:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Алло ты</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function getImage() {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);   
  return '<img src="\@3\'+random+'.jpg" border="0" />';
}

document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = getImage();
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = getImage();
</script>

<div>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Символ обратной косой черты (обратный слеш) `\` используется для [экранирования символов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2). Обратная косая черта как бы "сливается" с последующим символом (или даже несколькими символами) в единый символ. Посмотрите пример:

```js
console.log("\"\'\\\n\\\u0401");
```

Чтобы вставить в строку одиночный обратный слеш, напишите его дважды: `"\\"`. (Ещё про специальные символы на [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/string#spetssimvoly))

Также данная конструкция `Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);` возвращает целое число из отрезка `[0, 1]`, а номера файлов у вас начинаются с единицы. В общем, как-то так:

```js
    function getImage0() {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;   
        return '<img src=".\\@3\\' + random + '.jpg" border="0" />';
    }
    function getImage1() {
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;   
        return `<img src=".\\@3\\${random}.jpg" border="0" />`;
    }
    
    console.log( getImage0() );
    console.log( getImage0() );
    console.log( getImage1() );
    console.log( getImage1() );
```

Comment: Правда, что getImage0() и getImage1() являются одинаковыми функциями?

Comment: @NetscapeNavigator, работают они одинаково, но немного отличаются способом вставки переменной `random` в строку.